# How to manage en.yml for different api version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

How to break `en.yml` file with respect to version. I have some messages for `v1` version and messages changed in `v2` version of rails api. How to manage en.yml for different api version.

I don't want to overload my `en.yml` file for hundreds of action.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "v1" and "v2" in this context?

Comment: v1 and v2 are just namespace